# Вылетает приложение при переходе на фрагмент в Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android

проблема заключается в том, что я сделал 2 кнопки на фрагменте с одним обработчиком, они должны перебрасывать на 2 разных активити, но при открытии этого фрагмента на виртуальном устройстве приложение вылетает Хотелось бы с объяснением, что не так. Заранее спасибо. Вот вкладка Run:

```
        E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            Process: com.chemi.chemiapp, PID: 22938
            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                at com.chemi.chemiapp.FragmentOrgchem.onCreateView(FragmentOrgchem.java:28)
                at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
                at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
                at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**Java файл**

```
    `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
                import android.content.Intent;
                import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.view.LayoutInflater;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.view.ViewGroup;
                import android.widget.Button;


                /**
                 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
                 */
                public class FragmentOrgchem extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

                public FragmentOrgchem() {
                    // Required empty public constructor
                }



                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_inorgchem, container, false);
                    Button btn_spt = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_spt);
                    Button btn_yv = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_yv);
                    btn_spt.setOnClickListener(this);
                    btn_yv.setOnClickListener(this);

                    return view;

                }


                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    switch (view.getId()){
                        case R.id.btn_spt:
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SptActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;

                        case R.id.btn_yv:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YvActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

**XML файл**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".FragmentOrgchem">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_spt"
            android:layout_width="380sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
            android:background="#8B0F8B07"
            android:text="@string/spt"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_yv"
            android:layout_width="380sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="160sp"
            android:background="#E2AA08"
            android:text="@string/yv"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16sp" />

    </FrameLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве аргумента методу `setOnClickListener()` должен быть передан "живой" `Context`. При этом `this` в качестве контекста можно передавать только в активити, так как она является наследником класса `Context`, с фрагментом такой номер не пройдет.

Получить контекст в фрагменте вы можете методом `getActivity()`, например:

```
Context ctx = getActivity().getContext();
btn_spt.setOnClickListener(ctx);
btn_yv.setOnClickListener(ctx);
```